# RestTemplate exchange fail on GET call but works on CURL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate

I have the follow GET call works in CURL

```
curl -X GET 'https://us.api.blizzard.com/profile/wow/character/kiljaeden/n%C3%B8m?access_token=123&namespace=profile-us&locale=en_US'
```

But the following Java code gives 404 error

```
String testurl = "https://us.api.blizzard.com/profile/wow/character/kiljaeden/n%C3%B8m?access_token=123&namespace=profile-us&locale=en_US";

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

String out = restTemplate.getForObject(testurl, String.class);
```

Exact error

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 Not Found
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
```

Comment: You can visit http://webhook.site/ that will assign you a unique callback URL. Then send the request to that URL using CURL and using your code. That website will show you both requests, so you can easily check if there is a difference in the encoding of url parameters, in the headers, etc.

Comment: WOW thanks, this helped me alot. In the curl request, the part of the url is "n%C3%B8m", but then inside Java, RestTemplate turns it into "n%2525C3%2525B8m", how come?

Comment: The problem in Java is that you already URL-encoded that part of URL, and RestTemplate will URL-encode it again (escaping the % symbols, generating that additional stuff). So if you put the URL right in the code you should use the java default encoding (unicode), that is put "n\u00F8m" in the Java code instead of "n%C3%B8m". If you need to keep using "n%C3%B8m" in the Java code you should use URLDecoder to URL-decode the URL before using with RestTemplate.

Comment: ok thanks I award you the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "n%C3%B8m" part is URL-encoded, and RestTemplate is URL-encoding it again, escaping the % symbols, generating a different URL that causes the 404 error.

If you put the URL right in the code you should use the Java encoding (unicode), in this case use "n\u00F8m" instead of "n%C3%B8m".

If you need to support the "n%C3%B8m" format in the Java code you can use URLDecoder to URL-decode the String before using with RestTemplate.